# Send array from php to js with fetch()

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch-api

[image]
I have pscript.php file they have array $timeslots(). Array need a send to script.js used fetch(). How this do it? The files are in the same folder.

php:

```
$timeslots = array();
while ($cells = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  array_push($timeslots, $cells['rectime']);
}
```

js:

```
async function getResponse() {
  let respons = fetch('pscript.php', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    //body: JSON.stringify($timeslots)
})
  let content = await respons.json();
  console.log(content);
};

getResponse();
```

I tried send it with this code on php file

```
<script><?php echo json_encode($timeslots); ?></script>
```

and with it

```
echo json_encode($timeslots);
```

but html show me it

jsscript.js:7

```
   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: respons.json is not a function
at getResponse (jsscript.js:7:31)
at jsscript.js:11:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to `echo` the `$timeslots` array from PHP in an appropriate format (e.g. `echo json_encode($timeslots);`) after your `while` loop finishes (so that there's some JSON content for the JS to receive), and
2. you forgot to `await` the fetch, e.g. `let respons = await fetch('pscript.php', {` - see examples in many places e.g. https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json

Comment: i try echo, but it same thing. I add await and html send me new err: jsscript.js:5 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $timeslots is not defined
    at getResponse (jsscript.js:5:26)
    at jsscript.js:11:1
getResponse @ jsscript.js:5
(анонимный) @ jsscript.js:11

Comment: i think my err in body: JSON.stringify($timeslots) but idk what i should do

Comment: You don't need `body: JSON.stringify($timeslots)`..."body" is for _sending_ data to the server, not for receiving it. Clearly, `$timeslots` isn't a variable which exists in your browser/JS, it's a PHP variable on the server. You had commented that out in the code in your question, so I assumed you weren't using it. Look again at the examples in the link in my answer to see how to read the JSON data you receive from the server, and look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch to ensure you understand what all the options in the fetch() function are used for.

Comment: i comment that, but now html say i have syntax error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON

Comment: Presumably then your PHP script is either erroring (and showing a HTML-formatted error message), or returning more than just JSON alone. Check the raw response via the browser's Network tool

Comment: let me show you the code again just in case 
php:

$timeslots = array();
while ($cells = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  array_push($timeslots, $cells['rectime']);
}

echo json_encode($timeslots);

js: async function getResponse() {
  let respons = await fetch('pscript.php', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    //body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  let content = await respons.json();
  console.log(content);
};

getResponse();

Comment: I also attached a screenshot of the latest errors to the question

Comment: Ok. Well if that's the entire script then you _should_ be fine, but like I said there might be some kind of error or extra output. Did you do what I said and check the raw response?

Comment: P.S. You also really don't need `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` in your fetch, because you're not sending any data (especially not JSON data)

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about, Idk how to check the raw response. I looked somewhere that the request was executed, but the variable is not output to the console

Comment: everything is fine, I did it! thank you very much

Comment: It's in your browser's Developer Tools. Instead of Console, look at the Network tool while you are running your code, you'll see the fetch request to pscript.php appear there. Click on it, and you can then click on the "Response" tab within it to see what PHP returned